# What determines the color gamut of a display?

Tags: color, color-science, color-management

I’m not sure if I’m posting this question in the right area but, I’m wondering what determines the color gamut of a display?

Is or hardware down to the RGB filter built into a display like a monitor etc or is it software like a different color profile?

Question stems from the curiosity of if one display’s color gamut can be changed or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The physical imaging elements of your monitor define your gamut. So things like how bright the elements can be as well as the color spectra of the color elements define the gamut. But, thats quite the simplification, its also affected by such things as the screen surface material and background lighting conditions.

Can the gamut be changed? Sure, if you want a smaller gamut then you can restrict your colors to a subrange of your gamut.

Comment: So it’s more the physical hardware make up (rgb filter, pixel size, backlight) that determines the gamut than say software like a color profile?

Comment: @ohmmy  a color profile is a measurement of  a physical devices capabilities. You can emulate another device, and much of the standardisation has gone to define what to do when you can not reach the colors. But yes your gamut is fixed by the hardware. Obviously though if you have a wide gamut device it can emulate a device that is not so wide. So you can go down and you can use a intent to describe how to emulate when you can nlt.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense now that it’s hardware and can only emulate a gamut below what’s been designed originally